# Standard deviation of function of two RVs

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables

I've stumbled upon a problem that basically reduces to having two random variables
$$X \sim N(\mu_X,\sigma_X)$$
$$Y \sim N(\mu_Y,\sigma_Y)$$
and defining the third as
$$Z = \sqrt{X^2 + Y^2}$$
Although it would be convenient to have the exact expressions for mean and standard deviation I can safely assume the coefficients of variation $V_X$ and $V_Y$ are small, therefore I deduced
$$\mu_Z \approx \sqrt{\mu_X^2+\mu_Y^2}$$
but the standard deviation is giving me a hard time
$$\sigma_Z \approx \;??$$
Does anyone have any pointers on how to determine it?

**Answer:**

It turns out using a multi-variate Taylor expansion about $X = \mu_X, Y = \mu_Y$ leads to the best result, a first order approximation writes
$$Z \approx \sqrt{\mu_X^2+\mu_Y^2} + \frac{\mu_X}{\sqrt{\mu_X^2+\mu_Y^2}}(X-\mu_X) + \frac{\mu_Y}{\sqrt{\mu_X^2+\mu_Y^2}}(Y-\mu_Y)$$
such that
$$\mu_Z \approx \sqrt{\mu_X^2+\mu_Y^2}$$
$$\sigma_Z \approx \sqrt{\frac{\mu_X^2 \sigma_X^2 + \mu_Y^2 \sigma_Y^2}{\mu_X^2 + \mu_Y^2}}  $$

Comment: $$E[Z^2]=E[X^2+Y^2]=E[X^2]+E[Y^2]=(\mu_X^2+\sigma_X^2)+(\mu_Y^2+\sigma_Y^2)$$ and $\sigma_Z^2 = E[Z^2]-\mu_Z^2$.

Comment: Also, do you know what the _geometric mean_ is?

Comment: Okay, so that would basically leave me with $\sigma_Z \approx \sqrt{\sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2}$. Comparing this with a Monte Carlo simulation yields a significant discrepancy... Also, I messed up by calling this the geometric mean, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand how you got $\mu_Z$ but assuming you have it, by definition:

$$\sigma_Z^2 = Var(Z) = \left<Z^2\right>-\mu_Z^2$$

Now

$$\left<Z^2\right> = \left<X^2+Y^2\right> = \left<X^2\right>+\left<Y^2\right>$$

Which, using the difintion, $\sigma_X^2 = \left<X^2\right>-\mu_X^2$ becomes

$$\left<Z^2\right> = \left(\sigma_X^2+\mu_X^2\right) + \left(\sigma_Y^2+\mu_Y^2\right)$$

Therefore

$$\sigma_Z^2 = \sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2 +\mu_X^2 +\mu_Y^2 - \mu_Z^2$$

Comment: Indeed, this is what I got at first too. Simplifying the last expression by inserting $\mu_Z$ results in $\sigma_Z \approx \sqrt{\sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2}$, but that doesn't compare well with a Monte Carlo simulation... any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps you could check both the estimation and your method for easier cases first such as $\mu_x=\mu_Y=0$ and $\sigma_X=\sigma_Y$? Have you written the simulation yourself?

Comment: Yes, I checked that (using a Maple simulation) and it seems that only for very small coefficients of variation it is ok, for larger values the distribution of $Z$ becomes non-Gaussian. I think this is the best we can do :).

Comment: Right it seems like a Gaussian multiplied by an Erf. Still I think you could try to estimate it using a higher order approximation?

Comment: @demorge How does Guest86's answer differ from what I wrote in my comment? It is you who insists that $\mu_Z \approx \sqrt{\mu_X^2+\mu_Y^2}$ which gives $\sigma_Z\approx \sqrt{\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2}$ that does not match the Monte Carlo simulation. Does the simulation match the theoretical value of $E[Z^2]$? If so, it is the $\mu_Z$ which is not right.

Comment: @DilipSarwate No difference, indeed that $\sigma_Z$ is quite a rough approximation.

Comment: @Guest86 I've used a higher order multi-variate Taylor series expansion and this gives better result (although leading to lengthy expressions for very high accuracy), I've added the answer to my original post.